# ratio through convergence topologies

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

If $X$ is  sapce topological and two topologies $\tau_1$, $\tau_2$ both metrizable D1, D2 (metric).

If convergence with $D_1$ implies convergence with $D_2$, then It might from that condition, it could prove that $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$ or vice versa?

Thank you very much for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: since $(X, D_1), (X, D_2)$ are metric spaces, closed sets can be characterized with convergent sequences.

So, if $C \subset X$ is closed in $\tau_2$, one can show that $C$ is closed also in $\tau_1$. Let $x_n \to x$ be a $\tau_1$-convergent sequence in $C$ (i.e. $\{ x_n\}_n \subseteq C$ and $\lim_n D_1(x_n, x) = 0$). We want to show that $x \in C$. But this follows since $\lim_n D_1(x_n, x) = 0$ implies $\lim_n D_2(x_n, x) = 0$ and $C$ is closed in $\tau_2$. So $C$ is closed also in $\tau_1$.

This means that all closed sets of $(X, D_2)$ are closed in $(X, D_1)$, so $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think the conclusion is backwards:  $\tau_2$ is finer than $\tau_1$

Comment: No, $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$, so $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$.

Comment: That's right, I confused the definition, thank you very much